# Replace NAN values in a column from a data frame by unique values from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a data frame with many NANs, I would like to replace these values as specific names from a list.
The data frame:

```
index Color 
0      Red
1      Blue
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      Green
8      Yellow
....
165    Black
```

The list :

```
L=[yellow1,yellow2,red2,red4....]
```

I tried the following code to try to replace the NAN with the list values, but it does not really work:

```
index_NAN=df[df.color.isna()].index
length=len(index_NAN)

for i,j,k in zip(df.index, index_NAN,L): 
    if(i == j):
               df.color.fillna(k,inplace=True)
    else: 
         continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.loc`

```
L=['yellow1','yellow2','red2']
df.loc[df.Color.isna(),'Color'] = L
df
Out[115]: 
   index    Color
0      0      Red
1      1     Blue
2      2  yellow1
3      3  yellow2
4      4     red2
5      5    Green
6      8   Yellow
```